# Join multiple table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to leftjoin three tables in laravel.I give the same name for id in two tables for joining but i did'nt get the correct output.I did'nt get the whole id values only getting the joined ids

```
$products = DB::table('categories')
        ->leftjoin('subcategories', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
        ->leftjoin('products', 'products.subcat_id', '=', 'subcategories.subcat_id')
        ->get()->toArray();

Ouput

id  Category    Subcategory   Product
1   Lunch       Chinese       noodles
1   Lunch       Chinese       pizza
2   Breakfast   Indian        dosa
2   Breakfast   Indian        idly
    Dinner      
    Meals       
    xyz
```

Comment: Why don't you try using laravel's relationship with the model?

Answer (score 0):

you should use select like,

```
$products = DB::table('categories')
    ->leftjoin('subcategories', 'categories.category_id', '=', 'subcategories.category_id')
    ->leftjoin('products', 'products.subcat_id', '=', 'subcategories.subcat_id')
    ->select('products.id as productId', 'categories.id as categoriesId', 'subcategories.id as subCategoryId', 'categories.Category as Category', 'categories.Subcategory as Subcategory', 'product.name as product')
    ->get()->toArray();
```

I advise you to use product model first if you want to get all the products and in eager loading you should get all the other relational values.